# jQuery prevent keyboard press from working if target is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby on rails application where the user can go to a previous or next question using their keyboard. One page is loaded at a time, which contains the link to a previous page, and the next page.

What I want to do is that if the user is at the very first page, pressing the left keyboard arrow key should not work at all, since it will be undefined. Additionally, if the user is at the very last page, pressing the right keyboard arrow key should not work either, since the next page will be undefined. Right now, if the user is at the first or last page and presses the left or right arrow key respectively, it throws an error in my application saying that "undefined" url can not be found.

I got the prev/next functionality working, but now am confused on how to proceed.

```
$(function() {
   $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 37 :
        var a_href = $(this).find('a.previous_page').attr('href');
        window.location=a_href;
      break;
      case 39 :
        //window.location="/page-link-next";
        var a_href = $(this).find('a.next_page').attr('href');
        window.location=a_href;
      break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Where exactly are the questions you're referring to? Please include enough detail to answer.

Comment: Do you know about IF statements?

Comment: Sorry, added some details. I have an application which shows one page at a time, and I just want to fix the edge cases, which are the first and last pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.length` on a jQuery collection (such as `.find`) to figure out how many elements are in the collection.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `var` gets hoisted; having two `var`s declaring the same variable name inside a function isn't exactly valid. Better to declare the variable name elsewhere (such as at the top) and reassign, or use something other than a `switch` statement so you can use `const`, which has block scope and is a lot easier to deal with:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    const keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === 37) {
      const a = $(this).find('a.previous_page');
      if (a.length === 0) return;
      window.location= a.attr('href');
    } else if (keyCode === 39) {
      const a = $(this).find('a.next_page');
      if (a.length === 0) return;
      window.location= a.attr('href');
    }
  });
});
```

It's better not to use `switch` if you can avoid it - it's unnecessarily wordy and error-prone.

Comment: Brilliant. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "hoisted" in this context? I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: All `var` declarations inside a function are interpreted as if they were on the line(s) directly below the start of the function, eg for yours, `function(e) { var a_href; ... ... a_href = $(this).find(...`. This behavior is very unintuitive and causes problems - you'll be much better off using `const` instead, which has block scope and is not hoisted.